# Exercise 4.E - The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure by Bartle

Tags: measure-theory

$4.E.$ Let $f,g\in M^{+},$ let $\omega\in M^{+}$ be a simple function such that $\omega\leq f+g$ and let $\phi_{n}(x)=\sup\{(m/n)\omega(x): 0\leq 
m\leq n, (m/n)\omega(x)\leq f(x)\}$. Also let $\psi_{n}(x)=\sup\{(1-\frac{1}{n})\omega(x)-\phi_{n}(x),0\}$. Show that $(1-\frac{1}{n})\omega\leq\psi_{n}+\phi_{n}$, $\phi_{n}\leq f$, $\psi_{n}\leq g$.

I was able to prove the first two inequalities, it's just use the definition of $\phi_n$ and $\psi_n$ and observe that $f$ is an upper bound for the set $\{(m/n)\omega(x): 0\leq 
m\leq n, (m/n)\omega(x)\leq f(x)\}$, but I'm stuck in prove that $\psi_n \leq g$. Can anyone give me a hint in order to prove this inequality?

$\textbf{P.S.: read the comments of mojobask's answer.}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This holds when $ \omega \gt f $ :
$$ \omega/n \ge f - \phi_n
\\ \omega/n + \phi_n + \psi_n \ge f + \psi_n
\\ (1/n + (1-1/n)) \omega \ge f + \psi_n
\\ w \ge f + \psi_n 
\\ f + g  \ge w \ge f + \psi_n $$
Otherwise $ \psi_n = 0 $ and it holds trivially.

Comment: I tried separate in two cases: $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega < f(x)$ and $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega \geq f(x)$, but I couldn't realize why is valid the first and third inequalities that you put are valid when I tried solve this problem. Can you explain with more details this inequalities?

Comment: By definition  $\phi_n$ is less than a fraction of $\omega$ away from $f$ (whenever $\omega \ge f$ as $m$ may not exceed $n$). The third is what you get by adding  $\phi_n$ through the supremum in $\psi_n$.

Comment: I still do not see how the third line follows from the second: in fact, since, $\phi_n+\psi_n\ge (1-1/n)\omega$, the inequality goes in the wrong direction.

Comment: But under the condition $\omega \gt f$ it does hold that $\phi_n + \psi_n = (1-1/n)\omega$ , though not for $\omega = f$ which is my mistake.

Comment: I think that I understood the third inequality, it's because if $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega > f$, then

$$\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega > f \geq \phi_n \Longrightarrow \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega - \phi_n > 0 \Longrightarrow \psi_n =  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega - \phi_n \Longrightarrow \phi_n + \psi_n =  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega$$

This justify the third inequality.

Comment: But if $\omega>f$ it does not follow that for all $n,\ (1-1/n)\omega>f.$ If $\omega>f$ then you get $f-\phi_n<\omega-\phi_n\le (1-m/n)\omega\le (1-1/n))\omega.$ I still do not see how these inequalities are true.

Comment: I think that I understood the first inequality if $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega > f$, then $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega > \phi_n$. Indeed, if you have $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega \leq \phi_n \leq f$, which contradicts that $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega > f$. This justify the first inequality.

$$$$

Comment: @Driver8, I didn't separate by the cases $\omega \leq f$ and $\omega > f$ as mojobask did. I'm separate by the cases $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega \leq f$ and $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega > f$.

Comment: The case $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega \leq f$ is easy, since this imply that 

$$\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega \in \{(m/n)\omega(x): 0\leq 
m\leq n, (m/n)\omega(x)\leq f(x)\} \Longrightarrow \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega \leq \phi_n \Longrightarrow \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \omega - \phi_n \leq 0 = \psi_n \leq g$$

Comment: @Mathenthusiast: Nice proof. If you post it as an answer to your own question, I will be happy to upvote it.

Comment: Considering all the discussions under this answer, which is definitely an excellent way to learn mathematics, it wouldn't hurt to actually elaborate on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can argue by contradiction. Suppose on the contrary that $g(x)<\psi_n(x)$ for some $x$ and some $n$. Then $\psi_n(x)$ cannot be zero since $g \in M^{+}$. This implies that $\psi_n(x)>0$ or equivalently $(1-\frac{1}{n})\omega(x)=\frac{n-1}{n}\omega(x)>\phi_n(x)$. This contradicts the definition of $\phi_n(x)$.

Comment: Wouldn't you also have to check that $ \frac{n-1}{n} \omega (x) \le f(x) $? Otherwise, there's no contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x \in X$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
If $\psi_n(x)=0$, the result is immediate because then $g(x)\ge 0=\psi_n(p)$.
So we may assume $\psi_n(x)= \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\omega(x)-\phi_n(x)>0$.
Recall that $\phi_n(x)$ is the supremum of a finite set, so there is a nonnegative integer $m_0\le n$ such that $\phi_n(x)=\frac{m_0}{n}\omega(x)$.

Observe that $$ \psi_n(x)= \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\omega(x)-\phi_n(x) = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{m_0}{n}\right)\omega(x) >0$$
can only be possible if $m_0 \le n-2$. This fact provides us with two key inequalities:
$$ \frac{m_0+1}{n}\omega(x)>f(x)$$ and $$ \frac{m_0}{n}\omega(x)\le \phi_n(x).$$

The result follows now by some algebraic manipulation. Firstly,
$$\begin{align} g(x)&\ge \omega(x)-f(x)\\&>\omega(x)-\frac{m_0+1}{n}\omega(x)\\ &=\frac{n-m_0-1}{n}\omega(x), \end{align} $$

and secondly,

$$\begin{align} \psi_n(x)  & = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\omega(x)-\phi_n(x) \\ &  \le \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\omega(x)-\frac{m_0}{n}\omega(x) \\ & = \frac{n-m_0-1}{n}\omega(x) \\  &\le g(x), \end{align} $$

which concludes the proof.